# How to repeatedly execute a method without affecting the GUI until application exits? C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, timer, backgroundworker

I need to execute a method every 60 seconds until the application exits without slowing down the GUI using C# WPF.

The method being executed every 60 seconds checks a Boolean value in a Database Table. If the value is true the Application keeps running, if the value is false the application exits.

I have seen some posts using System.Threading.Timers, background workers and tasks.  However I do not know which is the best choice to use so that the GUI is still interactive

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: In WPF you should favor the use of a [`DispatchTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx) if possible.  This timer allows you to not have to worry about threading issues.

Comment: The DispatchTimer isnt guaranteed to run at the interval timer so i read @BradleyUffner

Comment: *None* of the timers in Windows are guaranteed to run at exact intervals.  That requires a "real-time OS", which Windows isn't.  In 99.99% of cases I've encountered, they are only a few *milliseconds* off.  No one will notice.  It's just a generic disclaimer.

Comment: If checking the database is a time-consuming operation, doing it in a DispatcherTimer's Tick handler might block the UI. You may then make the handler async and await a Task that checks the db, or you use some other timer class that, e.g. a System.Threading.Timer that runs on a ThreadPool thread. Note that you would have to use the application's Dispatcher to access the UI then.

Comment: @Rhysf93 The chances that any timer run at the exact time are slim to none. The scheduler will trigger them when "close" to the required time. But it's a matter of cpu cycles.

Comment: @Clemens currently its not a time consuming operation but i do plan to add afew extra lines to the code, if its not too much hassle could you provide an example as to how id go about it for the async and await or the system.threading.timer? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using the `DispatchTimer`, and `async` / `await`.  This is the preferred timer for *most* WPF applications.  You may need the other timers in some situations, but this one will handle the majority of WPF tasks.

The `DispatchTimer` allows the code to run on the UI thread, so you don't have to worry about manually dispatching the cross-thread operations.

The `async` / `await` calls allow the database operations (emulated here with a call to `Task.Delay`) to not block the UI.  You should replace the `Task.Delay` with the appropriate async DB operations, like `DbContext.SomeDbSet.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` if you are using Entity Framework.

The XAML just displays a checkbox that allows the application to exit when checked, and an animated label, to prove that the UI thread isn't blocked.

---

BetterWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace asyncTest
{
    public partial class BetterWindow : Window
    {
        public BetterWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private async void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // "async void" is generally frowned upon, but it is acceptable for event handlers.
            if (await ShouldExit())
            {
                Close();
            }
        }

        private async Task<bool> ShouldExit()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Checking the DB");
            //Simulate a long DB operation
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            return chkAllowClose.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault(false);
        }
    }
}
```

---

BetterWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="asyncTest.BetterWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:asyncTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="BetterWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel>
        <CheckBox Content="Allow Close" Name="chkAllowClose" DockPanel.Dock="Top"></CheckBox>
        <Grid>
            <Label Content="The UI isn't locked!" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" Width="200" Height="200">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="noFreeze" />
                    </Label.RenderTransform>
                <Label.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                        To="-360" Duration="0:0:10" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Label.Triggers>
            </Label>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score -1):

We're not on a real-time OS here, therefore it makes no sense to discuss the preciseness of the timers - they are never absolutely precise. But if we're talking about such time granularity as 60 sec, then it doesn't matter anyway.

So a timer *could* be an option, but I prefer another way:

```
public
MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var task = CheckToClose(cts.Token);
    Closing += delegate { cts.Cancel(); };
}

async
Task CheckToClose(CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        try { await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), ct); } catch (TaskCanceledException) { return; }
        var keepRunning = await ShouldKeepRunning(ct);
        if (!keepRunning)
        {
            Close();
            return;
        }
    }
}

Task<bool> ShouldKeepRunning(CancellationToken ct) =>
    // it's important here to take a thread pool task here so that working with the DB
    // doesn't block the UI
    Task.Run<bool>(
        delegate
        {
            // here you ask the DB whether you keep running
            // if working with DB is potentially too slow,
            // then take the CancellationToken into account
        });
```

Comment: An interesting solution. You shouldn't need to use `Task.Run` to avoid blocking the UI though. Simply using `await` on the db operations should avoid blocking the UI.  One other issue though, is that this will consume one thread from the thread-pool for the entire life of the application (assuming you fix the compilation error by using `await` when you call `CheckToClose`).

Comment: Simply using await will keep you in the UI thread and any blocking call to DB will consequently block it.

Comment: That's wrong...  The *entire* point of `await` is to wait for the results of an `async` operation without blocking the UI thread.  That's literally what it was designed for.

Comment: In order to avoid needless discussions, just copy my code into a blank project, then put a breakpoint anywhere in the CheckToClose method, which is async, then open the call stack in the debugger and see in the context of which thread you are.

Comment: Funny, I was going to suggest that you also study up on how async await actually works. It is pretty clear that you don't understand what is going on.

Comment: Funny or not, just try what I recommended. I'm sure you'll discover something new.

Comment: I [rewrote your code](https://pastebin.com/LfDBpgKH) to show you that when *properly* implemented, `async` / `await` does not require `Task.Run` to avoid blocking the UI.  I *highly* encourage you to learn how `async` / `await` really works before trying to teach others how to use it.  You are teaching others some VERY bad habits with your current statements.  Even my updated version of your code has serious issues though, `CheckToClose` doesn't exit until the application exits.  In your version, this blocks the constructor from completing, mine blocks an event. Both are BAD, don't do it.

Comment: You can see for yourself that the constructor never exits if you place a breakpoint at the end.  This code is actually DANGEROUS.  No one should be using this pattern.

Comment: The good thing about programming is that there's very little place left for "opinions" - everything is very easy to check. Did you try it with the breakpoints and the call stack? In the context of which thread are you in your ShouldKeepRunning method? Very simply - in the main thread.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Should i use the code you re-wrote? will this definitely run on a different thread and not block the UI until application exit? Thankyou for your help

Comment: @Rhysf93 No. even that code is fundamentally broken. I was just using it to show armenm that async / await doesn't require task.run.  I'm making an example for you now that is done to correct, safe way.  I will post it in a new answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @Rhysf93 try my code and see that it simply works. The code of Bradley Uffner will run on the primary thread and block the UI.

Comment: I've added an answer showing the *correct* way to do this.